# D3 selecting links while hovering nodes is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, variable-assignment

I am trying to make a node graph in D3 with hovering effects.
[example graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhL5Y.png)
or something like that:
[D3 - force-directed-graph-component](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph-component)

Currently I am using: D3V4.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@4

I'd like to have a effect on connected lines and nodes, while hovering a node.
But suddenly it wont work and the debugger tell me there is no known variable defined.

For easy debugging I made the stroke-width very high.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
    height = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;

// svg objects
var link, node;
// the data - an object with nodes and links
var graph;

// load the data
d3.json("data.json", function(error, _graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  graph = _graph;
  initializeDisplay();
  initializeSimulation();
});



let div = d3.select("body").append("div")
     .attr("class", "tooltip-circles")
     .style("opacity", 0);

let mouseOver = function(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", .5);
  d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 1);
  div.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 1);
  div.html(d.id)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 25) + "px");
  d3.selectAll(".links").filter(function(g) {
      console.log(d.id)
      console.log(g)
      return d.id === g.source || d.id === g.target;
    })
    .style("stroke-width",444)
  };

let mouseLeave = function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".circle")
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 1)
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
    div.transition()
      .duration('50')
      .style("opacity", 0)
    d3.selectAll(".links")
      .transition()
      .duration('200')
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("stroke", "000");
  }

//////////// FORCE SIMULATION //////////// 

// force simulator
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation();

// set up the simulation and event to update locations after each tick
function initializeSimulation() {
  simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
  initializeForces();
  simulation.on("tick", ticked);
}

// values for all forces
forceProperties = {
    center: {
        x: 0.5,
        y: 0.5
    },
    charge: {
        enabled: true,
        strength: -30,
        distanceMin: 1,
        distanceMax: 2000
    },
    collide: {
        enabled: true,
        strength: .7,
        iterations: 1,
        radius: 5
    },
    forceX: {
        enabled: false,
        strength: .1,
        x: .5
    },
    forceY: {
        enabled: false,
        strength: .1,
        y: .5
    },
    link: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: 30,
        iterations: 1
    }
}

// add forces to the simulation
function initializeForces() {
    // add forces and associate each with a name
    simulation
        .force("link", d3.forceLink())
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter())
        .force("forceX", d3.forceX())
        .force("forceY", d3.forceY());
    // apply properties to each of the forces
    updateForces();
}

// apply new force properties
function updateForces() {
    // get each force by name and update the properties
    simulation.force("center")
        .x(width * forceProperties.center.x)
        .y(height * forceProperties.center.y);
    simulation.force("charge")
        .strength(forceProperties.charge.strength * forceProperties.charge.enabled)
        .distanceMin(forceProperties.charge.distanceMin)
        .distanceMax(forceProperties.charge.distanceMax);
    simulation.force("collide")
        .strength(forceProperties.collide.strength * forceProperties.collide.enabled)
        .radius(forceProperties.collide.radius)
        .iterations(forceProperties.collide.iterations);
    simulation.force("forceX")
        .strength(forceProperties.forceX.strength * forceProperties.forceX.enabled)
        .x(width * forceProperties.forceX.x);
    simulation.force("forceY")
        .strength(forceProperties.forceY.strength * forceProperties.forceY.enabled)
        .y(height * forceProperties.forceY.y);
    simulation.force("link")
        .id(function(d) {return d.id;})
        .distance(forceProperties.link.distance)
        .iterations(forceProperties.link.iterations)
        .links(forceProperties.link.enabled ? graph.links : []);

    // updates ignored until this is run
    // restarts the simulation (important if simulation has already slowed down)
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}



//////////// DISPLAY ////////////

// generate the svg objects and force simulation
function initializeDisplay() {
  // set the data and properties of link lines
  link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class",  "links" )
        .attr("target", (d) => d.target )
        .attr("source", (d) =>  d.source  )
        .style("stroke-width", (d) => d.value);


  // set the data and properties of node circles
  node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", (d) => d.color)
    .style("stroke-width", (d) => d.width)
    .style('fill', (d) => d.color)
    .attr("class", function(d){ return "circle" } )
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver )
    .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave )
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended))
  updateDisplay();
}

// update the display based on the forces (but not positions)
function updateDisplay() {
    node
        .attr("r", forceProperties.collide.radius)
        .attr("stroke", forceProperties.charge.strength > 0 ? "blue" : "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", forceProperties.charge.enabled==false ? 0 : Math.abs(forceProperties.charge.strength)/15);

    link
        .attr("stroke-width", forceProperties.link.enabled ? 1 : .5)
        .attr("opacity", forceProperties.link.enabled ? 1 : 0);
}

// update the display positions after each simulation tick
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    d3.select('#alpha_value').style('flex-basis', (simulation.alpha()*100) + '%');
}



//////////// UI EVENTS ////////////

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;

}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.0001);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

// update size-related forces
d3.select(window).on("resize", function(){
    width = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
    height = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
    updateForces();
});

// convenience function to update everything (run after UI input)
function updateAll() {
    updateForces();
    updateDisplay();
};
```

I Compared many other solutions, but every other is calling all line, and this breaks the hover-end effect.
Something like:

```
link.style("stroke", "");", function(o) {
  return o.source === d || o.target === d
    ? '000' : 'AAA';
});
```

Is not helping and I would have to make every style attribute separate.
**I'd like to have a selectAll with a filter for better readability.**